# Chrome 93 doesn't use PCManFM-Qt dialog box anymore

Tags: google-chrome, lubuntu, dialog

I don't know this is a Lubuntu problem or a Chrome one so I post here first before heading to the Chrome bug tracker.

Previously, when I save something in Chrome, this dialog box is used:

[image: PCManFM-Qt]

Today, after updating to Chrome 93, this box pops up:

[image: no idea what]

How can I fix that?

Update: default file manager is still PCManFM-Qt.

[image: default file manager]

Update 2: [This Github diff](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/compare/93.0.4557.4...93.0.4566.0) contains the commit that cause the change. [Version 93.0.4566.0](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Linux_x64/898477/) is the first to exhibit this behavior. Here's the [changelog](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/93.0.4557.4..93.0.4566.0?pretty=fuller&n=10000) between it and its previous build.

Answer (score 0):

`preferences`--->`Default applications` for LXSession

change default file manager under '`lxsession-default-apps`'.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. The default file manager is still PCManFM-Qt.

Comment: @MinhNghĩa do use use dolphin ? if not then better to remove it

Comment: No I doesn't use Dolphin.

Comment: @MinhNghĩa remove it then - sudo apt-get remove dolphin

Comment: I mean I don't have Dolphin installed. `remove` or `purge` has no effect.